# Ruby on Rails Forms has_many with dynamic data from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, one-to-many

the main objective here is to allow each role of users to view and edit only some fields of other users. But roles will be in constant growth, so it needs to be dynamic.

I'm having trouble creating a new role listing all user's field even if the relationship doesn't exists yet.

[image]

I would like this:

```
  <%= form.fields_for :role_assignment do |role_assignment_form| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= role_assignment_form.text_field :user_field, disabled: true %></td>
      <td><%= role_assignment_form.check_box :show_permission, id: :role_show_permission %></td>
      <td><%= role_assignment_form.check_box :edit_permission, id: :role_edit_permission %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

To load like this:

```
User.attribute_names.map do |att|
  role.role_assignment.find_by_user_field(att) || RoleAssignment.new(role: @role,user_field: att)
end
```

What is shown is only the current registers. I don't even know where to put the code above...

Database diagrams for `Role` and `RoleAssignment`:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(12)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_role         | int(12)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_field      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| show_permission | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| edit_permission | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Models:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "role"
  has_many :user_role, foreign_key: :id_role
  has_many :user,  through: :user_role
  has_many :role_assignment, foreign_key: :id_role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :role_assignment, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class RoleAssignment < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "role_assignment"
  belongs_to :role, foreign_key: :id_role
end
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you explain `I'm having trouble creating a new role listing all user's field even if the relationship doesn't exists yet.` in this line what do you mean by `creating a new role listing all user's field`? As from the screen you shared it seems pretty ambiguous if you want to `create a new Role` or `create a new User`. Also I didn't get the use for `user_field` attr in `RoleAssignment`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the database description would be enough. Te new Role form creates Role and several RoleAssignment. The attribute `user_field` is the name of the field referencing Users' table and `show_permission` and `edit_permission` are the permissions for this field for this role. Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
# app/controllers/roles_controller.rb
role_assignment = @role.role_assignment

# You might not show these attributes, right?
blacklist_attributes = %w(id created_at updated_at)
user_attributes = User.attribute_names - blacklist_attributes

# Do not build existing user fields
(user_attributes - role_assignment.pluck(:user_field)).each do |user_field|
  @role.role_assignment.build(user_field: user_field)  
end
```

---

Should we use `role_assignments` (plural form) instead of `role_assignment` (singular form) in `:has_many`?

Comment: Thanks I'll try and came for the upvote if it works. I'm not making it plural because the database is shared with an older system, but thanks.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I've used your train of thought but slightly different things. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

@fongfan999's train of thought have helped a lot! But this is the complete answer for the specific question:

`/app/controllers/roles_controller.rb`:

```
class RolesController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    role_assignment = @role.role_assignment

    blacklist_attributes = %w(encrypted_password email_token forgot_token token provider uid oauth_token oauth_expires_at)
    user_attributes = User.attribute_names - blacklist_attributes

    (user_attributes - role_assignment.pluck(:user_field)).each do |user_field|
      @role.role_assignment << RoleAssignment.new(user_field: user_field)
    end
  end
end
```

`/app/views/roles/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_with(model: role, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :role_name %>
  </div>
  <% unless role.new_record? %>
    <div class="field">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Field</th>
          <th>Show?</th>
          <th>Edit?</th>
        </tr>
        <%= form.fields_for :role_assignment do |role_assignment_form| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= role_assignment_form.text_field :user_field, disabled: true %></td>
            <td><%= role_assignment_form.check_box :show_permission, id: :role_show_permission %></td>
            <td><%= role_assignment_form.check_box :edit_permission, id: :role_edit_permission %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Then I have redirected the save button to the edit form:

```
format.html { redirect_to edit_role_path(@role), notice: 'Role was successfully created now you can edit the permissions.' }
```

And the user experience is like this:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Thank you everyone for helping me solve it.